# Font size customization in tabular environment doesn't work

Tags: tables, tabularx, ieeeconf

I need to increase the font size of entries in my table. According to some former questions on `TEX.SE`, a potential solution like adding font size commands (such as \large) before beginning `tabular` environment must work. But in my case, such commands change nothing. How should I fix it?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption for the table.}
    \label{tab:table3}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \LARGE  ------> It affects nothing
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \toprule
        $$      & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & $^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$\\
        \midrule
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & occupied & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & & & occupied & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & occupied & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & & & occupied\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably it does affect something but with `resizebox` you can't see it...

Comment: I have to use that resizebox to confine the width of table to the column widrh .

Comment: Yes, but if the table has to stay in the column width `\LARGE` chars are resized to small ones. Run your code without `\resizebox` and you'll see that `\LARGE` works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `\LARGE`, but `\footnotesize`. Yes, really!

The problem is that you make a large table and then resize it to the columnwidth: even if you do `\HUMONGOUSLYHUGE`, the result would be exactly the same.

Remember: never do `\resizebox` for a table. Craft it as need be.

In this case, `\footnotesize` seems reasonable, together with a reduction of the intercolumns space and changing the big “occupied” with a symbol that you can explain in the text.

For typing the table, I used some local shorthands: I'm not suggesting to use `\STh` in place of `S^{h}(\theta^{h})` throughout your document, but just for this big table the shorthands help in readability of the code.

How did I determine the value for `\addtolength`? I typeset the table without it and got an overfull by 73.22162pt. Since there are 16 intercolumn paddings, I divided the amount by 16 and rounded up to the first decimal.

As an aside: `\tt` has been a deprecated command for more than twenty years. Use `\ttfamily` or the “command form” `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\ttfamily\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Caption for the table.}
\label{tab:table3}

%%% Local shorthands
\newcommand{\STh}{$S^{h}(\theta^{h})$}
\newcommand{\STv}{$S^{v}(\theta^{v})$}
%%% The definition of \occ could be in the preamble,
%%% if you use it also in other tables
\newcommand{\occ}{$\times$} % <--- change to your liking

\centering\footnotesize

%%% do the computation only at the very last moment
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4.7pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{9}{c}@{}}
\toprule
  & \STh & \STh & \STh & \STh & \STv & \STv & \STv & \STv\\
\midrule
\STh & \occ & & & & & &\\
\STh & & & & & & &\\
\STh & & & \occ & & & &\\
\STh & & & & & & &\\
\STv & & & & & & &\\
\STv & & & & & \occ & &\\
\STv & & & & & & &\\
\STv & & & & & & & \occ\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: whatever]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to enlarge the font size with a directive such as `\large` is utterly self-defeating in your setup because of the presence of the `\resizebox` instruction.

You need to go another route. I suggest you take the following steps:

- Instead of "occupied", write "occ.", so that the cell contents take up less space.
- Writing `S^{h}(\theta^{h})` and `S^{v}(\theta^{v})` takes up a lot of space. IN the code below, I suggest you typeset these terms much more compactly.
- Reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace. The default amount (2*6pt) is quite generous. Rather than adjust the parameter `\tabcolsep` in a trial-and-error fashion, I suggest you set it `0pt` right away and use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. That way, LaTeX will figure out the optimal (i.e., maximal available) amount of whitespace.

With these adjustments in place, all you need to do further is to set the table's font size to `\small`. The following screenshot provides a before-and-after comparison; I trust the "after" table is more or less what you were hoping to achieve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip,font={bf,sf}]{caption}
\newcommand\Sth[1]{S^{#1}\mkern-3mu(\mkern-2.5mu\theta^{\mkern-1mu#1}\mkern-2mu)}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock

%%%% First the "before" look
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Before}
    \label{tab:table3}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \LARGE % ------> It affects nothing
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \toprule
        $$      & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & $^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$\\
        \midrule
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & occupied & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & & & occupied & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{h}(\theta^{h})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & occupied & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & & &\\[0.5em]
        $S^{v}(\theta^{v})$ & & & & & & & occupied\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}

%%%% Now the "after" look
\begin{table}[h!]
\captionsetup{font={small,bf,sf}} % optional
\small
\caption{After} \label{tab:table3}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX calculate intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccccccccc}
\toprule
& $\Sth{h}$ & $\Sth{h}$ & $\Sth{h}$ & $\Sth{h}$ & $\Sth{\nu}$ & $\Sth{\nu}$ & $\Sth{\nu}$ & $\Sth{\nu}$\\
\midrule
$\Sth{h}$ & occ. & & & & & &\\
$\Sth{h}$ & & & & & & &\\
$\Sth{h}$ & & & occ. & & & &\\
$\Sth{h}$ & & & & & & &\\
$\Sth{\nu}$ & & & & & & &\\
$\Sth{\nu}$ & & & & & occ. & &\\
$\Sth{\nu}$ & & & & & & &\\
$\Sth{\nu}$ & & & & & & & occ.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```